# What is the most performance efficient method for retrieving 150 fields of data in a asp.net page?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2012

I have a asp.net page, which loads in about 150 fields of data from about 8 tables. It uses 1 sql view to pull in about 100 fields from one table, and then some SP's to bring in the rest from 7 other tables.

The page displays the fields using individual textbox's with runat=server, instead of using gridview.

I am not too proficient on asp.net methods of handling large pages and data, efficiently so..
What is the most server cpu efficient method of pulling all this data in?

Should I bundle it all into one huge sql view and use a gridview/repeater?

The html for the asp.net page is about 4000 lines long. It's starting to hit the server cpu fairly hard, 25% on each new page view/load.

Comment: You should only used a Repeater or GridView if for each row of data you want the same set of controls repeated multiple times.

Comment: Implement [pagination](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch) on the SQL Server side?

Comment: IMHO, forget _efficient_ in the current approach. Asking any _user_ to go through _150 fields_ in one go is what needs to be improved/rethought. I suspect if you redesign the flow from a user's perspective, you'll also get to better efficiency.